# Stripes with different direction for each region in RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting, regions

Could someone help me with a modification.

How could I modify my configuration and make each region striped with directions, i.e. horizontal, vertical and other directions? Since I get one colour for each region.

```
 ku = 1; km = 0.00004; \[Mu] = 8000 ; \[Epsilon]u = 0.0003; \[Epsilon]m = 0.00045; \[Alpha] = 0.95; \[Lambda]m = 0.00013; \[Lambda]u = 1; TL = 10; TL2 = 13;

shadowbox[legend_] := Graphics[{{White (*Color sombra de la figura geometrica*), Rectangle[]},{White (*Color de relleno interno*), EdgeForm[Black(*Color del contorno del cuadro*)],Rectangle[{-8, -12}(*punto izquier infierior*), {9,10}(*punto derec superior*)](*Dimenciones de figura (rectangle ejem) sobre el cual iran makers*)},Inset[legend, {0.5, 0.5}, Center]},ImageSize -> 60];

Legend1 = SwatchLegend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.3, 0.88],RGBColor[0.8, 0.57, 0.001, 1],RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.88],RGBColor[1, 0.95, 0.01, 0.8]},{Style["Reg. a", TL], Style["Reg. b", TL], Style["Reg. c", TL],Style["Reg. d", TL]},LegendMarkers ->Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[9], Rectangle[]}],LegendLabel -> "",LegendMargins -> 1,LegendFunction -> shadowbox];

RegionMRC = RegionPlot[{
            ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pu <= ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) &&km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pm <=km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pm <=km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu]) && pu == ku (pm/km)^(\[Epsilon]u/\[Epsilon]m)(*caso A*),
            ku (pm/km)^(\[Epsilon]u/\[Epsilon]m) < pu &&km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pm <=km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu])(*caso B*),
            ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pu <=ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) &&km (pu/ku)^(\[Epsilon]m/\[Epsilon]u) < pm(*caso C*),
            ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) <= pu &&km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu]) <= pm(*caso D*)
            },
            {pm, 0, 0.002}, {pu, 0, 20},
            PlotTheme -> {{"Monochrome", "VibrantColor", "Scientific"}},
            FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(ms\)]\)", TL2,Bold, Black],Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(us\)]\)", TL2, Bold, Black]},
            PlotLegends -> { Legend1},
            LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold],
            PlotRange -> {{0, 0.002}, {0, 20}},
            PlotStyle -> {{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.3, 0.88], AbsoluteThickness[0.3]},
            {RGBColor[0.8, 0.57, 0.001]},
            {RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.88],  AbsoluteThickness[0.5]},
            {RGBColor[1, 0.95, 0.01, 0.8], AbsoluteThickness[0.5]}},
            BoundaryStyle -> None(*{{Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}*)(*CONTORNO DE LAS REGIONES*), PlotPoints -> 100,PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

How can I modify?

Comment: With v12.1 and later there is [`HatchFilling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html)

Comment: Thanks, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

He podido resolverlo.

```
ku = 1; km = 0.00004; \[Mu] = 8000 ; \[Epsilon]u = 0.0003;
\[Epsilon]m = 0.00045; \[Alpha] = 0.95; \[Lambda]m = 0.00013;
\[Lambda]u = 1; TL = 10; TL2 = 13;

shadowbox[legend_] := Graphics[
                    {{White (*Color sombra de la figura geometrica*), Rectangle[]},
                    {White (*Color de relleno interno*), 
                    EdgeForm[Black(*Color del contorno del cuadro*)], 
                    Rectangle[{-8, -12}(*punto izquier infierior*), 
                    {9,10}(*punto derec superior*)](*Dimenciones de figura (rectangle ejem) sobre el cual iran makers*)},
                    Inset[legend, {0.5, 0.5}, Center]},
                    ImageSize -> 60];

Legend1 = SwatchLegend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.3, 0.88],
      RGBColor[0.8, 0.57, 0.001, 1],
      RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.88],
      RGBColor[1, 0.95, 0.01, 0.8]},
      {Style["Reg. a", TL], Style["Reg. b", TL], Style["Reg. c", TL], 
      Style["Reg. d", TL]},
      LegendMarkers -> 
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[9], Rectangle[]}],
      LegendLabel -> "",
      LegendMargins -> 1,
      LegendFunction -> shadowbox];

RegionMRC = RegionPlot[{
          ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pu <= ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) && km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pm <= km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu]) && pu == ku (pm/km)^(\[Epsilon]u/\[Epsilon]m)(*caso A*),
          ku (pm/km)^(\[Epsilon]u/\[Epsilon]m) < pu && km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pm <= km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu])(*caso B*),
          ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu] (1 - \[Alpha])) <= pu <= ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) && km (pu/ku)^(\[Epsilon]m/\[Epsilon]u) < pm(*caso C*),
          ku E^(\[Epsilon]u \[Mu]) <= pu && km E^(\[Epsilon]m \[Mu]) <= pm(*caso D*)
          },
          {pm, 0, 0.002}, {pu, 0, 20},
          PlotTheme -> {{"Monochrome", "VibrantColor", "Scientific"}},
          FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(ms\)]\)", TL2,Bold, Black],Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(us\)]\)", TL2, Bold, Black]},
          PlotLegends -> Placed[{Legend1}, Below],
          LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold],
          PlotRange -> {{0, 0.002}, {0, 20}},
          PlotStyle -> {
          {Directive[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.3, 0.88], Thick,HatchFilling["Diagonal", 1, 10]}]},
          {Directive[{RGBColor[0.8, 0.57, 0.001],HatchFilling["Vertical", 4, 6]}]},
          {Directive[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1, 0.88], Thick, Dashed,HatchFilling["Horizontal", 4, 6]}]},
          {Directive[{RGBColor[1, 0.95, 0.01, 0.8], Thin, Dashed, HatchFilling["Diagonal", 4, 6]}]}
          },
          BoundaryStyle -> None(*{{Black, AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}*)(*CONTORNO DE LAS REGIONES*), PlotPoints -> 100, 
          PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```